# Using a void pointer to store a 128 bit number in c

Tags: c

I am learning c. As an experiment I am trying to implement 128-bit addition and multiplication.

I want to do this using a void pointer as follows:

```
void* x = malloc(16);
memset(x, 0, 16);
```

Is it possible to read and write the ith bit of x? I understand how to do this using bitwise operations on standard data types but the compiler complains about invalid operands when I try and use bitwise operations on a void pointer. In general, I am interested in whether it is possible to malloc an arbitraryly sized block of memory and then manipulated each individual bit in c?

Comment: Post your code. BTW you cannot dereference `void *`. Use a different pointer type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The C standard is surprisingly (although logically) inflexible when it comes to casting of pointer types, although you can cast the result of `malloc` to any pointer type you want.

In order to perform bit and byte analsysis, a safe type to use is `char*` or `unsigned char*`:

`unsigned char* x = malloc(16);`

(I'd always pick the `unsigned char` since some platforms have a 1's complement signed `char` type which, crudely put, is a pain in the neck).

Then you can use *pointer arithmetic* on `x` to manipulate the memory block on a byte by byte basis. Note that the standard states that `sizeof(char)` and `sizeof(unsigned char)` is 1, so pointer arithmetic on such a type *will* traverse the entire memory block without omitting any bits of it.

As for examining bit by bit, the standards-defined `CHAR_BIT` will tell you how many bits there are in a byte. (It's normally 8 but it would be unwise to assume that.)

Finally, don't forget to call `free(x)` at some point.

Comment: @Aconcagua If `CHAR_BIT` might not be 8, you might as well make sure to handle all cases and round upwards: `malloc((128+CHAR_BIT-1)/CHAR_BIT)`

Comment: Actually, *only* `unsigned char` is guaranteed to not have any trap representation, i.e. the only "safe" type.

Comment: @user694733: Actually true... So far, however, I've never seen a system (still in use) not having a multiple of 8 as CHAR_BIT, so I did not have these in mind... But I've seen one or another 16-bit processor, so...

Answer (score 2):

To set a bit at position `i`

```
*((uint8_t*)x + i/8) |= (1 << (i%8))
```

To clear it

```
*((uint8_t*)x + i/8) &= ~(1 << (i%8))
```

Comment: So just cast to `uint8_t` and then this answers the question. Though array notation is easier to read. `x[i/8]` and so on